Looking for a book about an alien lost or stranded on earth and the people it comes in contact with
The book first gives the alien's view of its interactions then gives each of the people's view of the same interaction.
The chapters were all named after the people who came in contact with the alien. Some only had one chapter some had multiple and those people came in contact with each other and had chapters of those interactions.
The first was a young girl I had thought she was a junkie or addicted to drugs if I remember right the alien fell in love with her or was an empath and felt for her in a way.
The second was a street gangster named shark or something similar who lived his life trying to live up to the characters in A Clockwork Orange and the book and character mention that book quite often on the things and way the gangster kid acts feels.
I always remember the book as Millennium by Dean R. Koontz but can not find anything named that by him nor anyone else with the same story line. The book was a paperback novel I found  around 1997 or so probably 200 to 300 pages if not more, don't think it was much older than the timeframe I read it
I remember the cover was all black with Millennium across it then the authors name Koontz .

This could well be Millennium, a book from 1994 but written by the journalist Jack Anderson, rather than Dean R. Koontz.
The plot indeed deals with an alien who is stranded on Earth. He encounters a street punk called "Ghost" (rather than "Shark"), and from a BookList review:

A renegade alien attempts to visit the president to warn him of the
impending demise of the human race, but fails to accomplish his
mission. Sent away by a bored White House security guard, he's
promptly mugged by a gangbanger named Ghost who makes off with the
alien's diabolical mind-control device. While the now invincible Ghost
goes on a rampage, a supersecret government agency responsible for
suppressing information about extraterrestrials springs into action,
and soon doctors, cops, a street preacher, and a cokehead socialite
are all caught in the web of deceit. There's plenty of action and lots
to ponder here, but hokum and self-aggrandizement almost scuttle the
story once Anderson introduces his hero: a longtime Washington
columnist named Mick Aaronson.

The "cokehead socialite" may be the junky the OP recalls, and is named Serena Blake.
I can also confirm that the chapters were named after the main character participating in it. Several chapters were titled "Ghost", some were 'Harry Lauter" (a street preacher who gets involved in the plot), and so on. One of the covers was indeed mainly black, with "Millennium" written across it.

